# Replacement of expressjs's app.use() method in Hapijs?

Tags: node.js, express, hapi.js

How can I replace below code in Hapijs?

```
var testRouter = require('./testRouter');
module.exports = function(app) {
app.use('./test',testRouter);
}
```

Can anyone help me to convert this code into Hapijs ?

Comment: Please share your views if you are doing downvote. Please

Answer (score 2):

Read hapi's docs, in particular read on how to register a route [here](https://hapijs.com/api#serverrouteoptions).  Alternatively check out this [module](https://github.com/devinivy/hecks) for reusing express code in hapi.

Comment: All info you require is there, check the module called hecks if you want a quick and dirty solution

Answer (score 0):

```
server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/test',
    handler: function(request, h) {
        return h.response("Test").code(200)
    }
});
```

You can also load up your routes like this.

```
server.route([{
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/test-1',
        handler: function(request, h) {
            return h.response("Test1").code(200)
        }
    },
    {
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/test-2',
        handler: function(request, h) {
            return h.response("Test2").code(200)
        }
    }
]);
```